# Actionscript 3 - How To Detect Collision Of Transparent Sprites

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, transparency, sprite, collision

I have a sprite that shows a rectangle and has `alpha = 0;` and I want it to be positively tested for collision. Is that possible with full transparency and pure Flash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [bounding box](http://www.actionscriptmoron.com/AS3Tutorials/hittest-hittestobject/) collision checks.

If the rectangle of a sprite overlaps another, they are colliding.

Comment: Whoops, I made a mistake. But you pointed me to the solution anyways thx!